# Building a Docker image from a manifest

Tags: docker

I got this manifest.json and all layers needed to build a Docker image, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I actually build and push this image to my local registry? With `docker import` I can import all the individual layer.tar files but that doesn't help me a whole lot. I also looked into the experimental `docker manifest push` but I can't figure out what a MANIFEST_LIST is in the limited [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/manifest_push/).

edit: I already added all the layers individually, here they are:
[image]

Comment: Can you run `docker images` to list all your images ?

Comment: I edited the post, these are the relevant docker images, but that's just the individual layers

Comment: Before you push your local image to `local registry` or `remote registry`, you have to tag your image! and then if you want to `push` to `local registry` you have to configuration your `locate docker daemon` server.

Comment: How did you solve this one? I have several layers of the type "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip"

Answer (score 1):

After we run a image, we actually also create a container. and we can commit this container as a new image:

```
commit -a='frank' -m='new image' cbd18c36d22c 192.168.0.123:5000/frank/hello
```

And here, you have already create some image, just forgot to name it. but you can also given a tag .(Assume you have locate registry with *192.168.0.123:5000* address)

```
docker tag cbd18c36d22c 192.168.0.123:5000/frank/hello
```

And then you should list you commit by `docker images`.

```
192.168.0.123:5000/frank/hello   latest              cbd18c36d22c        2 weeks ago         349MB
```

To let the `docker daemon` know where to pull your images, you have to config it (Seems you are run docker on `Mac`). you can `Client the Preference -->Daemon -->Basic` and then input your `192.168.0.123:5000` into the `insecure registries`.

Finally, restart the `docker daemon` by click the `Apply & restart`.